# cert-manager did not get expected response when querying endpoint, expected <token> but got: <html xml:lang=\"fr-FR\" l... (truncated)"

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I have configured a ClusterIssuer

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    email: <myemail>
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

and An Ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: web-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hostname
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: web-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - hostname
      secretName: web-cert-tls
```

I'm unable to get the configuration to run properly. This spawns a new ingress as follows

```
Name:             cm-acme-http-solver-9nbh6
Labels:           acme.cert-manager.io/http-domain=1234
                  acme.cert-manager.io/http-token=1234
                  acme.cert-manager.io/http01-solver=true
Namespace:        default
Address:          <IPAddress>
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host          Path  Backends
  ----          ----  --------
  hostname  
                /.well-known/acme-challenge/challengexyzxyzxyz-o   cm-acme-http-solver-9dc8z:8089 (10.2.0.85:8089)
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    10m (x2 over 10m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Here's the describe for Ingress which is applied by me

```
Name:             web-ingress
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=web-app
Namespace:        default
Address:          <IPAddress>
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
TLS:
  web-cert-tls terminates hostname
Rules:
  Host          Path  Backends
  ----          ----  --------
  hostname  
                /   web-service:3000 (10.2.0.68:3000)
Annotations:    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: true
                cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
                kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age                  From                       Message
  ----    ------             ----                 ----                       -------
  Normal  CreateCertificate  31m                  cert-manager-ingress-shim  Successfully created Certificate "web-cert-tls"
  Normal  Sync               6m27s (x6 over 31m)  nginx-ingress-controller   Scheduled for sync
```

and when I check the cert-manager logs I find this error

```
E0905 10:09:04.617600       1 sync.go:190] cert-manager/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="did not get expected response when querying endpoint, expected \"challengexyzxyz.morestuffherexyzxyz\" but got: <html xml:lang=\"fr-FR\" l... (truncated)" "dnsName"="hostname.ovh" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="web-cert-tls-xtp2r-768063107-2100049723" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
```

When I access `hostname/.well-known/acme-challenge/challengexyzxyzxyz-o` from browser
I'm getting the expected value.

When I access it from a pod I'm getting an html that says domain purchased page.

I've also tried to just apply the certificate without the Ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: web-cert
  namespace: default
spec:
  dnsNames:
    - hostname.ovh
  secretName: web-cert-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

I've also tried adding `acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"` to Ingress object annotation, It didnt solve the problem either. ( It didnt spawn a new ingress that's all )

so I'm stuck at this stage of challenge

```
Type:         HTTP-01
  URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/12134567898/Fmasf
  Wildcard:     false
Status:
  Presented:   true
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: did not get expected response when querying endpoint, expected "challengexyzxyzxyz-o.challengexyzxyzxyz-o" but got: <html xml:lang="fr-FR" l... (truncated)
  State:       pending
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      dnsPolicy: "None"
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
```

Setting this config for cert-manager worked out.

It was `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst` And it somehow was pointing to dns provider's website saying congrats on purchase.

Turns out that, it also can be a propagation delay for the dns that's local to the k8s provider. In my case the delay was more than 24h. Once the nameserver was updated I could revert this change and still got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was happening because I am running Certmanager on a homelab cluster that sits behind an Opnsense router which my domain name points to. Opnsense was not configured by default to enable a Hairpin NAT. So any requests, from within my network, to my domain name would instead redirect to my router's login page. Hence the confusing error message from Cert Manager about an unexpected response starting with `<!doctype html>`.

Checking these three boxes fixed it. Took me hours to figure out :sweat_smile:

[image: Screenshot 2023-10-22 at 2 40 39 PM]

Comment: In our case the Problem was the "Reflection for port forwards" and this fixed it for us. Solid answer if you use "pFSense" or "OpnSense".
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making sure that `tls` in spec is present of ingress

```
 spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - deck.spinnaker.abc.com
    secretName: spin-deck-tls
```